# Using CDN in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, cdn

I've installed React via NPM and I'm having difficulty using CDN.
 I included the CDN scripts in the `./public/index.html` file but when I use it in any component, it doesn't recognize the third-party package that I'm trying to use.

> `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>`

Tried to use Axios but it doesn't work:

```
axios.post("https://burger-builder-c5a0d.firebaseio.com/orders.json", order)
            .then(response=>{
                alert("You ordered successfully!");  //shows an alert indicating a successful process
                console.log(response); //sends results to the server
                this.setState({
                    showModal: false, //closes the modal
                    loading:false,
                    purchasable: false
                })
               
            }).catch(error=>{
                       this.setState({
                            showModal: false,
                            purchasable: false,
                            loading: false
                        })
                console.log(error);
            })
```

Tried to use redux and it's also not being recognized

```
const reduxStore= redux.createStore;
       const store =  createStore();
```

[Here's the error that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqWaU.png)

Comment: Why not just install `axios` with `npm`? This seems like a better solution so that your dependencies are not added in multiple ways.

Comment: I was going to do that but I had absolutely no space on my hard drive to install Axios or other packages believe it or not but I recently freed some space and installed all the packages via NPM and they work successfully. Aside from that, I have another problem which is I wanna pass props to another component "without rendering that component to the dom" Just passing props through. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you considered using something like `CodeSandbox`, `StackBlitz`, `CodePen`, `Glitch`, or similar cloud-based solutions? Use the cloud if you don't have space on your machine. Also, not sure what you mean - you just want to pass your `props` through a component? Something like `Higher Order Components`? https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the axios or redux package via require?
Like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
```

**EDIT**

You're right. You don't even need to require something since you're importing from the CDN

I tried with the HTML boilerplate from the React.js documentation and imported the CDN from your source.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      function fetch() {
        axios
          .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
          .then(response => console.log(response.data));
      }
      ReactDOM.render(<h1>{fetch()}</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
    <!--
      Note: this page is a great way to try React but it's not suitable for production.
      It slowly compiles JSX with Babel in the browser and uses a large development build of React.

      Read this section for a production-ready setup with JSX:
      https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project

      In a larger project, you can use an integrated toolchain that includes JSX instead:
      https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

      You can also use React without JSX, in which case you can remove Babel:
      https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've applied to what you wrote but it gave me an error saying "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'axios'" and "Module not found: Can't resolve 'axios'".

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to import `Redux` and `Axios` via CDNs, although they both are available as NPM packages.

Anyways, You can simply import any CDN script by using `createElement()` of ReactJs.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };
```